# Mountebank imposter ports not accessible when mountebank started using dotnet-testcontainers

Tags: docker, mountebank, service-virtualization

I am using `dotnet-testcontainers` https://github.com/HofmeisterAn/dotnet-testcontainers to spin up a container with mountebank in my xUnit test.
I can successfully create a mountebank client and create an imposter successfully.
The issue is that when the test is run, the app tries to make a call to the imposter on `http://localhost:3000` and gets connection refused.

I can successfully open `http://localhost:2525` and can see Mountebank default page. So mountebank is running fine. I also confirmed that the imposter was created successfully on port `3000` by looking at docker container log.
I also tried to use Postman to make a call to my imposter at `http:localhost:3000` and get connection refused.

What could be the issue? Is this an issue that port `3000` in the docker container is not exposed or something? Below is my code:

```
MountebankClient mbClient = new MountebankClient();

var testcontainersBuilder = new TestcontainersBuilder<TestcontainersContainer>()
                .WithImage("bbyars/mountebank")
                .WithName("mountebank")
                .WithPortBinding(2525, false)
                .WithHostname("localhost");

var testContainers = testcontainersBuilder.Build();
await testContainers.StartAsync();

var testImposter = mbClient.CreateHttpImposter(3000);
testImposter.AddStub().ReturnsBody(HttpStatusCode.OK, File.ReadAllText(@".\Stubs\testImposter.json"));
mbClient.Submit(testImposter);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be useful for someone else who would face this issue. Figured out what the issue was. I was not mapping the host port and the imposter port in the container. Read about published ports https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/ and used `WithExposedPort(3000)` and then did port binding of that port with host port using `WithPortBinding(3000,3000)` where the `first` port in this method is host port and `second` port is container port.

```
var testcontainersBuilder = new TestcontainersBuilder<TestcontainersContainer>()
        .WithImage("bbyars/mountebank")
        .WithName("mountebank")
        .WithPortBinding(2525, 2525)
        .WithExposedPort(3000)
        .WithExposedPort(3100)
        .WithPortBinding(3000, 3000)
        .WithPortBinding(3100, 3100)                 
        .WithWaitStrategy(Wait.ForUnixContainer().UntilPortIsAvailable(2525))
        .WithHostname("localhost");
```